# Integrating Solspace "tags" to generate a RSS feed

Tags: tags, rss

I use Solspace tags in my EE template to build a relationship with related articles. For another site, I now want to combine Solspace tags in my RSS template to build customized rss feeds.

I've found this resource as well http://ablognotlimited.com/index.php/articles/customizing-expressionengine-rss-template/

Looking for "how-to" insights before purchasing another instance of Solspace for another site.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking here? Its unclear. You want to use Tag to do what with RSS exactly?

Comment: we want to be able to generate an rss feed specific to a tag. so for example, if we had a tag for "research" and tagged several articles with "research", we want to be able to create a rss feed that just contains those research articles.